# How can I insert records from one sandbox to another sandbox?

Tags: data-loader, sandbox, migration-tool, create-records

I have sandbox shared for my team and I have personal sandbox. How can I insert records sandbox shared for my team to my personal sandbox? I have required objects and fields.
I don't need to insert all records. Mainly I need insert records only for one object.

Comment: Have you tried using data loader?

Answer (score 3):

If you're comfortable with the command line and have the Salesforce CLI installed, try using `sfdx force:data:tree:export` and `import` commands.

See an end to end example [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_test_data_example.htm)

**Update Oct 2020**

I've also recently discovered that the [Salesforce inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-inspector/aodjmnfhjibkcdimpodiifdjnnncaafh?hl=en) Chrome extension has a Data Export and Data Import button.  Simply write an SOQL query in Data Export in the source org, use the copy as CSV button, and paste into Data Import in the destination org, and you're done!

Answer (score 2):

You can try using dataloader or workbench to insert/export records from the sandbox to your personal sandbox.

First, try to export records in .csv format from your team sandbox and you can filter spreadsheet as per the records list which you want to insert in your personal org.

Since you have same fields and object name in both org's you can auto-match fields directly.

Review below links and steps involved using Dataloader.

[Using Dataloader](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=inserting_updating_or_deleting_data.htm&type=5)

Thanks,